# jquery click event not firiing even with ON method

Tags: jquery

I'm stumped.

I've created a link that popups a form that works great.

Here's what the link looks like:

```
<a class="buttonA right popForm" m="guest">form</a>
```

In the form it ajax's a php page and besides all the other gobbledygook, 
it pulls these two more relevant lines:

```
<a class="buttonA right closeForm">X</a>
<a class="test">test</a>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
$J(document).ready(function () {
    $J(".popForm").click(function () {
        var t = $J(this).attr("m");
        var id = ($J(this).attr("id") !== undefined ? $J(this).attr("id") : 0);

        $J.ajax({
            beforeSend: function () {
                //console.log(1);
            },
            url: "popForm.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: ({
                "t": t,
                "id": id
            }),
            success: function (results) {
                $J("#popup").html(results);
                $J("#popup").show();
            }
        });
    });
    $J(".test").on("click", function (e) {
        console.log("e"+e);
        alert('aa');
    });
    $J(".closeForm").on("click", function () {
        alert(333);
    });
});
```

Now I'm expecting my "X" link to close the form (or in this case to alert me with 333),
but the link is dead.
Actually, both links are dead.

I've all but run out of clever debugging ideas

- I'm running the most recent jQuery lib
- I don't have preventDefault anywhere in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.on()` but in a `delegated-events approach` like:

```
$J("#popup").on("click", ".test", function (e) {
    console.log("e"+e);
    alert('aa');
});
$J("#popup").on("click", ".closeForm", function () {
    alert(333);
});
```

**IF `#popup` was not present in the DOM at the time you clicked your *"call popup"* buttons -
 instead of `#popup` use some other parent element!**

http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This element could be the container element of a view in a Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready.

jQuery will than act like:

```
$J("#popup").on(    // Ohh I know this guy it's in the DOModel!
                    // let's see what event bubbling will he listen for...
     "click",       // hihi, I know this event! That event should descend from...
     ".closeForm",  // hm, there's no such fella yet, 
                    // but if one day if I find him...
     function () {  // I'll show him what's a function!!!
          alert(333);
     }
);
```

Comment: dude you rock - is it cuase i needed to put the parent elem first?  i cant just use the elem?

Comment: @toy If `#popup` is generated afterwards, from PHP, than it should be any other popup's parent element that is already on the page on DOM ready. Alternatively you can use `$(document)`, but it's not suggested to listen so deep for events bubbling

Comment: @toy - And if my answer helped you (as the other 3 questions you have already collected) you'd be pleased to accept all the unaccepted answers you have!